# extract value from nested documents from 3x nested array ( mongod 4.0.23)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Please, help , I have following document type:

```
{
_id: 1,
"_a": [
  {
    "_aId": {
      "CC": "CA"
    },
    "_p": [
      {
        "_pId": {
          "CC": "CA"
        },
        "s": {
          "c": {
            "t": [
              {
                sId: 1,
                language: "CA",
                format: "A4"
              },
              {
                sId: 2,
                language: "JP",
                format: "A4"
              }
            ]
          },
          "a": {
            "t": [
              {
                sId: 4,
                language: "CA",
                "format": "A4"
              },
              {
                sId: 5,
                language: "EN",
                "format": "A3"
              }
            ]
          },
          "d": {
            "t": [
              {
                sId: 10,
                language: "CA",
                "format": "A4"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    }
  ]
 }
```

And I need faster solution to extract all subdocuments sId for language:"CA" & format:"A4" for documents with "_a._p._pid.CC":"CA"

So the expected output need to look as follow:

```
  {sId:1}
  {sId:4}
  {sId:10}
```

I have an index on "_a._p._pId.CC" and I have tried with 2x $unwind , but collection is pretty big and it take some time to unwind  , any suggestion highly is welcome?

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jwxFnMqJkVv)

mongod 4.0.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: rmoved `$first` to match mongodb version 3.6:

One option is:

1. `$reduce` to `res` the objects under `_a._p.s`
2. Use `$objectToArry`, since there are different key names.
3. `$reduce` again to get a flat array of `t`s.
4. `$filter` the array to keep only wanted items.
5. Format the response.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      res: {$reduce: {
          input: "$_a",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$reduce: {
                  input: "$$this._p",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this.s"]]}
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {res: {$map: {input: "$res", in: {$objectToArray: "$$this"}}}}},
  {$project: {
      res: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$res",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$reduce: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.v.t"]}}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      res: {$filter: {
          input: "$res",
          cond: {
            $and: [{$eq: ["$$this.language", "CA"]}, {$eq: ["$$this.format", "A4"]}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$res"},
  {$project: {sId: "$res.sId"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iaIn6B_1CFK)

Comment: Many thanks @nimrod serok !   Unfortunately missed to mention the deployment is using abit older  mongodb version 4.0.23 and is throwing me this error: "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$first'" :( , but for 5.0 working as expected ...

Comment: This can be easily solved like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0CAR1qm_zSZ). Will `_a` always have only one item, or there can be few?

Comment: If `_a` can have several items, use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iaIn6B_1CFK)

Comment: There can be multiple items in _a , thanks alot for the hints!